# Do you know of any major gotchas with using PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, prism

I am looking at implementing PRISM into my next silverlight & WPF application.

I have read quite a bit about it and have implemented several sub patterns already in projects BUT I wanted to check with the community if there are any major gotcha's that other developers have come across when using the PRISM pattern that I should keep in mind for my future projects.

Comment: Have you looked on the http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF site? We (patterns & practices) are about to start work on Prism V4 so would love to hear any feedback you have WRT things that are hard to do with the existing version (V2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialogs - I found it difficult to fit truly decoupled dialogs into my MVVM/Prism based application.

Comment: I agree, it definately takes a different mindset to get dialogs working... especially messageboxes, which I would typically put in my ViewModel... which seemed out of place?

Comment: Since there really hasnt been much activity with this question.. I am going to give this one to you Sean...